# Problems with delete in hash perl

Tags: perl, hash, logic, string-length

Another hash contains name as key (split by _) and has 4 parts(I am comparing the first three parts). The value is a string whose length i need to compare and If the name is same and already exists in the hash (the first three parts), I need to keep the string with longest length and if the lengths are equal, I don't care which one it keeps. I know with iteration it is creating issues as the key-value pairs are being deleted.

```
 my %temphash=();
 %temphash=%anotherhash;
 foreach my $tempkey(keys %temphash){
        my @tempkey_splitted = split /\_/, $tempkey;
        my $tempkey_newfamily = $tempkey_splitted[0];
        my $tempkey_newgenera = $tempkey_splitted[1];
        my $tempkey_newspecies = $tempkey_splitted[2];
        my $tempkey_catstring ="$tempkey_newfamily"."_$tempkey_newgenera"."_$tempkey_newspecies";
        my $sequence_realkey="";
        my $sequence_tempkey="";
        my $length_realkey="";
        my $length_tempkey="";
        if ($realkey_catstring eq $tempkey_catstring){
            $sequence_realkey = $anotherhash{$realkey};
            $length_realkey = length($sequence_realkey);
            #print "$anotherhash{$realkey}";
            #print "$length_realkey";
            $sequence_tempkey = $temphash{$tempkey};
            #print "$anotherhash{$tempkey}";
            $length_tempkey = length($sequence_tempkey);
            # print "$length_tempkey";

            if($length_realkey>$length_tempkey){
                delete($temphash{$tempkey});
               #print ">$realkey\n$anotherhash{$realkey}\n\n";
                }
            elsif($length_tempkey>$length_realkey){
               delete($temphash{$realkey});
               #print ">$tempkey\n$anotherhash{$tempkey}\n\n";
                }
            elsif($length_tempkey eq $length_realkey){
                delete($temphash{$realkey});
                }
            }
        else{
             print "do nothing"; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: take a look at [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) it allows you to safely delete entries while iterating.

Comment: As a warning, when using `each`, do take care to loop until the end or you'll find the next time you enter the loop you'll only get the remainder of the hash you didn't iterate over the last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite convoluted, but I think the example code below does what you need. It works by copying the contents of `%anotherhash` (*please* don't use such dreadful meaningless names for your variables) to `%temphash` one element at a time, and only if the new value from `%anotherhash` is longer than the `%temphash`

```
my %temphash;

while (my ($key, $val) = each %anotherhash) {

  my @key = split /_/, $key;
  my $tempkey = join '_', @key[0,1,2];
  my $tempval = $temphash{$tempkey};

  unless (defined $tempval and length $tempval >= length $val) {
    $temphash{$tempkey} = $val;
  }
}
```

Comment: lol.I will remember not to use dreadful names! I have been working on it for a while got tired of naming! but i think this should work! Thanks :)
Wait but this won't get my the 4th part of the name which i need in the final output!

Comment: So take the example and modify it. after all, your nickname is Tonks 'Can' Code.  I don;t think anybody here wants to write the entire solution for you. We're just here to E.D.G.E - Explain, Demonstrate, Guide, Encourage.

Comment: Giving your variables dreadful names probably increases tiredness :) If you write readable code and add some comments as to why you are doing what you are doing it gets easier to troubleshoot, and you'll be glad you added the comments if you look at the code again half a year later.

Comment: @tonkscancode: If you explained properly how you want `%temphash` to look after the procedure and gave some example data then we could help you better. As it is I have had to work backwards from the code you show and try to understand what you meant it to do. There are still things I don't understand, like where do `$realkey` and `$realkey_catstring` come from, and what `$sequence_realkey` and `$sequence_tempkey` are for (you create them but don't use them). Also your own code doesn't do anything special to keep the fcomplete key so I have nothing to go on.

Comment: will definitely be adding comments once i figure it out! Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!